# pdf reading ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad

I am working on a pp where I need to open a pdf and read as ebook. I need to create the index which must be having the pages of the pdf. Now I have following doubts:
 I am not able to figure out how to show the the pages as index(thumbnail).

how to get to the clicked page of pdf? I mean can I open a particular page of the pdf.

Can i also allow user to click on a link in the pdf and play the video?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could take a look at the following code: https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Links in the pdf that point to an external source will be opened in safari as far as I know.

Comment: i have checked that and it solved many of my requirement but I still have a big task of playing a video over click of a link/image in pdf.